# HVAC control & Low Voltage Wiring (24v to 10v)

Tags: motor-controller, 24v, spdt, hvac

I am a GC having some exhaust fan control issues I am hoping someone on here can assist with. My mechanical and electrical contractors are stumped as well.

We have a [Vari-green 2 speed controller](https://www.stinebaugh.com/wp-content/uploads/GREENHECK-VARI-GREEN-Motor-Controls.pdf) connected to an exhaust fan in an LN2 Closet, and a [PureAire O2 Deficiency Monitor](https://www.pureairemonitoring.com/all-categories-gas-monitorsair-check-o2-oxygen-deficiency-monitor-for-co2-n2-storage-areas/) mounted on the wall above the Ln2 Dewars.

The ideal situation would be the monitor alarming due to excessive off-gassing of LN2, this would send a signal to the 2 speed controller that would increase the exhaust fan from low speed (A) to high speed (B) until the alarm resets and the fan would return to low speed (A).

The issue we are having is making the connection between the two units. Greenheck wiring diagram is requesting an external 0-10v SPDT switch or relay for dry contact, and PureAire is requiring a constant 24v common jumper to their relay. My assumption would be that the pureaire monitor will function as the relay, the issue being the voltage difference.

One of my contacts who works with controls advised the following connections:

**Greenheck to PureAir** (see attached diagrams)

Drycontact Common to Relay 2 Common

Drycontact A to Relay 2 Normally Closed (NC)

Drycontact B to Relay 2 Normally Open (NO)

This makes sense on a functionality standpoint. However, when I reached out to the reps at PureAire, they said we must have a 24v jumper from the mainboard to each relay as shown in the contactor wiring.

*“Our relays work where N.C contact will always have 24v when not in alarm state and 0v when in alarm state and the N.O. contact has 0v in normal state and 24v in alarm state. These relays are rated to 2 amps max.”*

I would greatly appreciate any help with this matter.
[image]

Comment: The manual says you can use either "Dry contact input" or "AC digital input". Can you get 110VAC and neutral from the Fan and use "AC digital input" instead? Manual also says: "DO NOT CONNECT BOTH DRY CONTACT AND DIGITAL INPUTS SIMULTANEOUSLY"

Comment: We could run a digital connection, but the issue is we need to connect the two units together so that the oxygen monitor will trip the controller into changing speeds. Dry-contact seems to be the only option.

Answer (score 1):

According to page 8 of the [Vari-green 2 speed controller manual](https://www.stinebaugh.com/wp-content/uploads/GREENHECK-VARI-GREEN-Motor-Controls.pdf) there are two ways to change speed:

[image]

Comment: I understand this is an option for the fan controller itself, but I am not seeing an option to connect the controller to the oxygen monitor via AC digital input. We need to connect this monitor to the controller. https://www.pureairemonitoring.com/all-categories-gas-monitorsair-check-o2-oxygen-deficiency-monitor-for-co2-n2-storage-areas/

Comment: What does the "Relay 2" output in the "Oxygen/Universal Monitor" do?